# Perpendicular view on corners/edges in sculpting mod

Tags: sculpting

would like to ask if there is a possibility to make our view perpendicular on edges/corners/sides (ecs) while we are in sculpting mod in other angles beside the front/right/top (so on) ortho views that we have. Perhaps some kind of ... line that will be show when we are exactly 90° on the specific corner/edge/side that we wish to work.

I know it sounds silly the question, but I'm confronting a small issue with this matter when I try to use smooth brush on ecs. If there is not a 90° view on the specific zone where I want to edit (ecs) the brush won't work, and if it will work and still not on the right angle, it will distort the model badly on the one side while on the other might not even touched it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can change to orthographic view by pressing keypad number 5 (note that it is not the number 5 above the letter keys on your keyboard). That way you have an orthographic view on whatever you are/look/zoom. To change back to perspective way, press again the same key.

Answer (score 1):

if you <kbd>tab</kbd> into edit mode, you can use <kbd>Shift Numpad 7</kbd> to look down perpendicular on the active face / selection. This also aligns to edges, but along the edge, not perpendicular to it. Perpendicular alignment is possible with using <kbd>Shift Numpad 1</kbd> when having one edge or two vertices selected. Toggle between Ortho and Perspective using <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>

<kbd>tab</kbd> out of Edit Mode again to return to sculpt mode.